# Writing to .csv more than one column

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, dictionary, writer

I have this code:

```
#//Running my argument to check if the item in list is in dictionary and returning    this + corresponding value in dictionary//#
for key in n:
    if DICT.get(key):
        print ((key) + ' : ' + DICT[key])
    else:
        print((key) + ' : ' + "Not Available")

#Writing to .cvs file       
with open('test_write.csv', 'w') as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp)
    a.writerows(n)
```

I want to have the result in the above for loop written to .csv.
At the moment I am getting each letter of the first part of the code in separate columns.
I need to have the both one in each column..
I suggest that I need to convert the for loop to a dict? But I could be wrong...

Any ideas on how to do this the easiest?

EDIT:
Using your sugestion:

```
    with open('test_write.csv', 'w') as fp:
        a = csv.writer(fp)
        for key in n:
        if DICT.get(key):
            print ((key) + ' : ' + DICT[key])
            a.writerow(n)
        else:
            print((key) + ' : ' + "Not Available")
            a.writerow(DICT.get(n,"Not Available") for name in n)
```

I am not getting what I was expecting
I am getting 4 rows of my list n.
With no indication of the value in the DICT. 
What am I doing wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`writerows` takes a list of iterables. Try using `writerow`.  From the looks of things, `n` is a dict, so to get a row of headers and a row of values, do:

```
a.writerow(n.keys())
a.writerow(n.values())
```

You *could* write `a.writerow(n)` for the first line, but I prefer to show this a little more explicitly.

And a little shortcut to add all the default values:

```
names = ['list','of','all','expected','keys']
data = {'list':'A', 'of':'zoo', 'keys':'foo'}
default = dict.fromkeys(names,"Not Available")
default.update(data)
data = default
```

Leaving data with the contents:

```
{'all': 'Not Available', 'of': 'zoo', 'list': 'A', 'expected': 'Not Available', 'keys': 'foo'}
```

**EDIT**:

Given DICT = {1:a, 2:b, 3:c, 4:d} and a list n = [1, 2, 5, 6], just do:

```
a.writerow(n)
a.writerow(DICT.get(name,"Not Available") for name in n)
```

will print two rows to your CSV file, one with the key names in n, and one with the values from DICT, or the words "Not Available" if a particular key is not in DICT.

**EDIT2**:

You are trying too hard - DICT.get will take care of whether an entry exists or not:

```
with open('test_write.csv', 'w') as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp)
    a.writerow(n)
    a.writerow(DICT.get(name,"Not Available") for name in n)
```

Here is the same code, with a little more verbose form:

```
with open('test_write.csv', 'w') as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp)
    # write row of header names
    a.writerow(n)

    # build up a list of the values in DICT corresponding to the keys in n
    values = []
    for name in n:
        if name in DICT:
            values.append(DICT[name])
        else:
            values.append("Not Available")
    # or written as a list comprehension:
    # values = [DICT[name] if name in DICT else "Not Available" for name in n]
    # 
    # or just use DICT.get, which does the name checking for us, and chooses the 
    # default value if the key is not found
    # values = [DICT.get(name, "Not Available") for name in n]

    # now write them out
    a.writerow(values)

    # or finally, the list build and writerow call all in one line
    # a.writerow(DICT.get(name,"Not Available") for name in n)
```

**EDIT**:

```
    # to write out the transpose of the previous lines (that is, instead of 
    # a line of names and a line of the matching values, a line for each
    # name-value pair), use Python's zip builtin:
    for nameValueTuple in zip(n,values):
        a.writerow(nameValueTuple)
```

Comment: Paul Thank you. n is actually a list. Does this matter much?

Comment: Then just write `a.writerow(n)`. This will give you the list of headers, like the names in my example. Assuming you will get the values from DICT, then you can follow with `a.writerow(DICT.get(name,"Not Available") for name in n)`

Comment: More info: I have a DICT = {1:a, 2:b, 3:c, 4:d} and a list = [1, 2, 5, 6] I rund the for loop to check if item in list is in DICT key if yes then I want it to return list item and DICT key. in two colums in csv. Hope it makes it clearer. THANKS

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU. No one last thing. It prints it horisontaly. Each item in a column can this be done so that each item appears in a row and the value in the column next to it. :) I can do this in excel but would be easier to do it with python i think